# Mktime returns different values

Tags: c++

I have a class for operations with dates.
When I try to intialize it with the same values,the first instance works fine but all the others return different values every time.I keep the dates in time_t DATE variable.

Its constructor :

```
CDate (int y,int m,int d)
    {
     tm * datetmp ;
     datetmp = localtime (&DATE);
     datetmp->tm_year = y - 1900;
     datetmp->tm_mon = m - 1;
     datetmp->tm_mday = d;
     DATE=mktime ( datetmp );
    }
```

Main:

```
CDate a ( 2000, 1, 30 );
CDate b ( 2000, 2, 27 );
cout <<a.DATE <<endl;
cout << b.DATE << endl;
```

The results after each run:

949240864
951646384

949240864
951605568

949240864
951632960

949240864
951617456

949240864
951662240

Comment: how `DATE` is declared?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `DATE` is never initialized before you call `localtime()` on it. It appears that in the `a` case, that initial value happens to be the same each time. In the second case, it's not. Either way, it's undefined and you shouldn't rely on its being consistent.

Comment: just time_t DATE; under public (for debugging from main) in CDate

Comment: Oh god,it actually was because I forgot to intialize DATE.I am new to SO,should I delete this post or leave it be?

Comment: @user2308001 I suppose purpose of your constructor is to initialize DATE field, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure how this code should work, but I suppose you want something like this:

```
CDate (int y,int m,int d)
{
    tm datetmp;
    memset(&datetmp, 0, sizeof(datetmp));
    datetmp.tm_year = y - 1900;
    datetmp.tm_mon = m - 1;
    datetmp.tm_mday = d;
    DATE = mktime(datetmp);
}
```